# Count files occurrences linux

Tags: linux, awk, count

I want to count the number of times each word in column 3 occurs. Below is the input

```
IN A three
US B one
LK C two
US B three
US A one
IN A one
US B three
LK C three
US B two
US A two
IN A two
US B two
```

Output should look like:

```
IN A three    4
US B one      3
LK C two      5
US B three    4
US A one      3
IN A one      3
US B three    4
LK C three    4
US B two      5
US A two      5
IN A two      5
US B two      5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a way;

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{++a[$3]; next} {print $0, a[$3]}' file file
IN A three 4
US B one 3
LK C two 5
US B three 4
US A one 3
IN A one 3
US B three 4
LK C three 4
US B two 5
US A two 5
IN A two 5
US B two 5
```

#### Explanation

It loops through the file twice: firstly to fetch data, secondly to print it.

- `FNR==NR{++a[$3]; next}` when looping for the first time, keep track of how many times the 3rd value appears.
- `{print $0, a[$3]}` when looping for the second time, print the line plus the counter value.

To have a nicer output you can also use `printf` to print a tab after the 3rd column:

```
{printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, a[$3]}
```

Comment: Just as a curiosity when reading same file more than once, you can in most shell change `file file` to `file{,}` So this should work `awk 'FNR==NR{++a[$3]; next} {print $0, a[$3]}' file{,}`.  Try `echo 1{,,}`

Comment: Wow that's brilliant, thanks @Jotne. I won't change the answer as it may look confusing, but definitely writing it in my cheat sheet :)

Comment: Hai fedorqui you can add this also to your cheat sheet along with Jotne's approach if you wish `awk 'FNR==NR{++a[$3]; next} {print $0, a[$3]}' $(printf 'file %.0s' {1..2})`, its bit lengthy but if you have to input many files say 10 times same file then this might be useful try `echo $(printf 'file %.0s' {1..10})`

Comment: @jaypalsingh is back in the awk field :) great news!!